# Ansible Chocolatey failing mysteriously?

Tags: windows, azure, ansible, chocolatey

I am trying to run an ansible playbook on an Azure VM, but I am running into a strange problem. Attempting to install any software (attempted git, sysinternals, nscp) just doesn't fire.

```
win_chocolatey:
        name: git
        state: present
```

Does not even trigger an install attempt. Nothing in the logs other than attempting to list the software. It just attempts to list the software, and throws out that it's not present (because said software is not installed)

```
win_chocolatey:
        name: git
        state: absent
```

Works perfectly fine, after manually installing git. I have tried installing the package manually using the command win_chocolatey would use (according to the docs) and it works. Using the exact same user as the playbook is. (has admin rights)

I've also tried to force the admin account with `become`, (even though it already runs admin) but it mattered not.

`-vvvv` is not even showing an install attempt either:

```
TASK [Download and install chocolatey packages] **************************************************************
task path: /usr/user/clouddrive/windows-vm/create-vm-windows.yml:162
Using module file /opt/ansible/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_chocolatey.ps1
<my.ip.address.here> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: AzureAdministrator on PORT 5986 TO my.ip.address.here
checking if winrm_host my.ip.address.here is an IPv6 address
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
failed: [my.ip.address.here] (item={u'choco_name': u'git', u'choco_state': u'present'}) => {
    "changed": false,
    "command": "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin\\choco.exe list --local-only --exact --limit-output git",
    "item": {
        "choco_name": "git",
        "choco_state": "present"
    },
    "msg": "Error checking installation status for the package 'git'",
    "rc": 2,
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Am I missing something? The docs (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_chocolatey_module.html#examples) say that even something basic like:

```
- name: Install git
  win_chocolatey:
    name: git
```

Should install the package (state present or not, I've tried it with no state, and any other, only `absent` works)

Comment: this looks like it has to do with a breaking change in 0.10.12 (https://chocolatey.org/docs/release-notes)

Comment: @Madison Please add this as an answer so I can upvote and close, injecting the disabled enhanced exit code before the task fixed the issue! Thank you!!

Comment: Also make sure to link to https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1758, where we point to Ansible already applying fixes to handle these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhanced exit codes were added to Chocolatey 0.10.12 which is listed as a breaking change.

[chocolatey.org/docs/release-notes](https://chocolatey.org/docs/release-notes)

Ansible changes are already being made to fix this (see [github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1758](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/1758)), but for now you can disable the feature per the release notes

```
choco feature disable --name="'useEnhancedExitCodes'"
```